# Template static definition and explicit specialization instantiation errors in MSVC

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, explicit-specialization, explicit-instantiation

I'm wondering why the following code runs just fine in gcc

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct F { 
  static T const value;
};

template<> 
struct F<int> { // Specialization
    static int const value; 
}; 

template struct F<int>;

template<typename T>
T const F<T>::value = sizeof(T);

template<>
int const F<int>::value = 42;

int main() {

    struct F<int> ma;
    cout << ma.value;

    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/wvrurz

while on MSVC 2012 I cannot get it to compile:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct F {
  static T const value;
};

template<> 
struct F<int> { // Specialization
    static int const value; 
};

//template struct F<int>; // error C2950: 'F<int>' : cannot explicitly instantiate an explicit specialization

template<typename T>
T const F<T>::value = sizeof(T);

//template<>
//int const F<int>::value = 42; // error C2998: 'const int F<int>::value' : cannot be a template definition

int main() {

    struct F<int> ma;
    cout << ma.value;

    return 0;
}
```

From what I read in n3242 §14.7 5

> both an explicit instantiation and a declaration of an explicit
>   specialization shall not appear in a program unless the explicit
>   instantiation follows a declaration of the explicit specialization.

and I believe this is the case. Am I missing something?

Comment: Your interpretation seems perfectly reasonable to me.

Comment: The program is not ok, but not because of what you say, but because `template<> int const F<int>::value = 42;` should be without `template<>` (latest gcc [correctly diagnoses](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c039a2ebc6cd75c7) it). The explicit instantiation *does* follow the explicit specialization declaration (which is also a definition), though.

Comment: GCC has a lot of extensions, that permit you to do things the C++ standard doesn't allow. These are on by default. Will it still allow this with the "-ansi -pedantic" flags to compile?

Comment: @EvanDark interestingly on coliru 4.8 it gives the error jrok reported. Still not sure for C2950

Comment: @MarcoA. C2950 looks like a bug in VC 2012. VC 2013 [compiles this line fine](http://rextester.com/ZHR6981).

Comment: Could you paste us the compile errors? Also, try setting the compiler language to c++11.

Comment: @deek0146 Compiler errors are in comments inside the code. No settings are needed to enable C++11 in VC 2012/2013. It is enabled by default.

Comment: Yes, C2950 is [an already fixed (in VC 2013) bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/753981).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### TOO LONG; DIDN'T READ

- *msvc 2012* is correctly rejecting the line marked `// error C2998`,
- the former diagnostic is however faulty and should be accepted; as it is in [newer versions](http://rextester.com/LKOTC73710) of the compiler.

<sup>**Note**: The bug report related to C2950 can be found, [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/753981)</sup>.

---

### Regarding [C2950](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9045w50z%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

*msvc 2012* is wrong to issue a diagnostic for the line in question.

```
template<class T> struct A;

template<>
struct A<int> { };

template struct A<int>; // legal

int main () { }
```

The standard states that an explicit instantiation should contain a *simple-template-id*, which is exactly what `A<int>` is, and with that said; it is **legal** *C++*.

> `14.6.2p3` **Explicit instantiation** `[temp.explicit]`
>
> > If the explicit instantiation is for a class or member class, the *elaborated-type-specifier* in the *declaration* shall include a *simple-template-id*.

> `14.2p1` **Names of template specializations** `[temp.names]`
>
> > A template specialization (14.7) can be referred to by a *template-id*:
> >
> > ```
> > simple-template-id:
> >          template-name < template-argument-list_opt >
> > ```

**Change of wording:** *C++03* vs *C++11*

*14.7.2p5* has some new wording starting from *C++11*, which was put in place after the following *defect report*:

- [**259**. Restrictions on explicit specialization and instantiation](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#259)

> `14.7.2p5` **Explicit instantiation** `[temp.explicit]`
>
> > For a given set of template arguments, if an explicit instantiation of a template appears after a declaration of an explicit specialization for that template, the explicit instantiation has no effect.

> <sup>**Note**: Kudos to *@[dyp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/420683/dyp)* for bringing attention to the previously linked *DR*.</sup>

---

### Regarding [C2998](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01d7zzfy%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

This error is accurate; you are not referring to something which depends on a template-parameter, this means that you should not use `template<>` on the definition in question.

Newer versions of `gcc` issues a diagnostic regarding it,  and *clang* correctly rejects such a definition.

```
template<class T> struct A;

template<>
struct A<int> { 
  static int const value;
};

template<> int const A<int>::value = 42; // ill-formed, `value` does not depend on
                                         //              any template parameter since it's
                                         //              explicitly a part of `A<int>`

int main () { }
```

```
gcc   => foo.cpp:8:22: warning: too many template headers for A<int>::value (should be 0)
clang => foo.cpp:8:1: error: extraneous 'template<>' in declaration of variable 'value'
msvc  => foo.cpp(8) : error C2998: 'const int A<int>::value' : cannot be a template definition
```

The above diagnostics are correct.

The line in question is a violation of the following section of the Standard:

> `14.7.3p5` **Explicit specialization** `[temp.expl.spec]`
>
> > Members of an explicitly specialized class template are defined in the same manner as members of normal class, and not using the `template<>`syntax. The same is true when defining a member of an explicitly specialized member class.